# Export LinqPAD results to Excel file without the rowcount metadata

Tags: linqpad

I was trying to write to an excel file just the resultset from a query but I keep getting the header column with the row count, which is messing up the subsequent data processing I need to do.  I could go in the exported file and delete the first row, but it would be much better if I could export a dataset without the header row.

Here's my hack, I wonder if anyone has a better way to do it. I am taking the generated html and using regex to yank out the header row:

```
public string DumpToHtmlString<T>(T objectToSerialize, string filePath )
    {
        string strHTML = "", outpuWithoutHeader ="";
        try
        {
            var writer = LINQPad.Util.CreateXhtmlWriter(true);
            writer.Write(objectToSerialize);
            strHTML = writer.ToString();
            outpuWithoutHeader = Regex.Replace(strHTML, "<tr><td class=\"typeheader\"((\\s*?.*?)*?)<\\/(tr|TR)>", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, outpuWithoutHeader );

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, "Investigate why ?" + exc);
        }
        return outpuWithoutHeader;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the `objectToSerialize` an IEnumerable? If so, the [LINQPad beta](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx) has a `WriteCsv` method which is designed to create Excel-friendly CSV files:

```
Util.WriteCsv(data, @"c:\temp\results.csv");
```

Otherwise, you're safer using the LINQ-to-XML DOM for modifying the output rather than regex. The following code illustrates how to remove formatting from LINQPad output; you can adapt it to remove headings and totals as well:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load (...);
XNamespace xns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

doc.Descendants (xns + "script").Remove ();
doc.Descendants (xns + "span").Where (el => (string)el.Attribute ("class") == "typeglyph").Remove ();

doc.Descendants ().Attributes ("style").Where (a => (string)a == "display:none").Remove ();

doc.Descendants (xns + "style").Remove ();
doc.Descendants (xns + "tr").Where (tr => tr.Elements ().Any (td => (string)td.Attribute ("class") == "typeheader")).Remove ();
doc.Descendants (xns + "i").Where (e => e.Value == "null").Remove ();

foreach (XElement anchor in doc.Descendants (xns + "a").ToArray ())
    anchor.ReplaceWith (anchor.Nodes ());

var presenters = doc.Descendants (xns + "table")
    .Where (el => (string)el.Attribute ("class") == "headingpresenter")
    .Where (e => e.Elements ().Count () == 2)
    .ToArray ();

foreach (var p in presenters)
{
    var heading = p.Elements ().First ().Elements ();
    var content = p.Elements ().Skip (1).First ().Elements ();

    if (stripFormatting)
        p.ReplaceWith (heading, new XElement (xns + "p", content));
    else
        p.ReplaceWith (
            new XElement (xns + "br"),
            new XElement (xns + "span", new XAttribute ("style", "color: green; font-weight:bold; font-size: 110%;"), heading),
            content);
}

// Excel centre-aligns th even if the style says otherwise. So we replace them with td elements.
foreach (var th in doc.Descendants (xns + "th"))
{
    th.Name = xns + "td";
    if (!stripFormatting && th.Attribute ("style") == null)
        th.Add (new XAttribute ("style", "font-weight: bold; background-color: #ddd;"));
}

string finalResult = doc.ToString().Replace ("Ξ", "").Replace ("▪", "");
```

Comment: If all you need to do is suppress the summary totals at the bottom of Dump output a simple hack is add .ToString() to numeric members types. Then Dump() will not show the summary row with totals. e.g. If all you need to do is suppress the summary totals at the bottom of Dump output a simple hack is add .ToString() to numeric members types. Then Dump() will not show the summary row with totals. e.g.  var n = new []{1,2,3};
 n.Select(x => x.ToString()).Dump();